# Automation tools able to trigger an action after detecting a sound

Tags: automated-testing

I have a system that at certain point makes a sound like a "beep". When that sound comes we need to perform an action, but we do not know at what time the "beep" will occur. We want to capture the sound when running an automation script then once we get it perform an action.

**Can any automation tools detect a sound then trigger an action?**

Comment: I don't know of any tools that can detect a sound, but there may be tools that can catch the event which triggers the sound. You might have to work with your programming team to get a hook into the code which generates the sound to be able to automate this scenario.

Comment: What is your desired platform?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like one option is https://www.zonetrigger.com/sound-detection/

> "Use any sound capture device!
>
> Audio Zone Trigger can capture sound from any source available on your
>   computer's mixer, and from any sound-capable device:   Microphone
>   Webcam with sound   Computer's own mixer output   USB sound capture
>   devices
>
> For each volume detecting trigger, you can choose from a wide range of
>   actions that Zone Trigger will perform. Recording audio, playing
>   sounds, executing commands on the computer... only a click away."

I have no connection to the company. No idea how good their stuff is.

Answer (score 1):

Another more "build you own" answer might be [here](https://community.mydevices.com/t/barkbox-simple-noise-intrusion-detection-device/2582).

Answer (score 1):

For Android one option you might use is - StackOverflow [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10838970/trigger-event-on-sound-input-from-mic).

Which leads to this - [NoiseAlert source code](http://code.google.com/p/android-labs/source/browse/trunk/NoiseAlert/src/com/google/android/noisealert/SoundMeter.java?r=2)